# add style attribute inside using php

Tags: php, html, echo

I have this inside my php file:

```
echo '<div class="tab_icon tab_'.(empty($post_format) ? 'standard' : $post_format).'" >';
```

And I want to insert also a style attribute here.

This is my attempt:

```
echo '<div class="tab_icon tab_'.(empty($post_format) ? 'standard' : $post_format).' style="background-image: url('.get_post_image( $post->ID, "small").');" " >';
```

but is not working proper, the output is this :

```
<div class="tab_icon tab_image style=" background-image:="" url(http:="" thehue.co="" wp-content="" uploads="" 2013="" 09="" untitled-22-194x150.jpg);"="" "=""></div>
```

How can I correctly apply the style attribute inside this ?
Thank you!

Comment: You are opening a `<?php ?>` tag inside an `echo`, of course you'll get an error.

Comment: looks like you're also missing a `"` to close the `class="`

Comment: I've updated my question, please take a look now

Comment: Add a double quote (") right before the space for the style in the PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You have another `echo` function inside the first `echo`.
You can't place an echo inside another echo.

2) You are opening PHP tags inside an echo and they were open from before hand.

This is the correct way:

```
echo '<div class="tab_icon tab_'.(empty($post_format) ? 'standard' : $post_format).' style="background-image: url('.get_post_image( $post->ID, "small").');" " >';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to echo an echo statement inside of an echo statement.  (I'm sure the parser error you reference is trying to tell you this...)  This doesn't make sense:

```
echo 'some string'<?php echo 'some string' ?>;
```

You don't need the `<?php echo ... ?>` construct when you're already in the context of server-side code.  Just remove it:

```
echo '<div class="tab_icon tab_'.(empty($post_format) ? 'standard' : $post_format).' style="background-image: url('.get_post_image( $post->ID, "small").');" " >';
```

Comment: @Alecs: Are you sure that's your *exact* code?  What string value does `get_post_image( $post->ID, "small")` actually return?

Answer (score 0):

try ;

```
echo '<div class="tab_icon tab_'.(empty($post_format) ? 'standard' : $post_format).' style="background-image: url(\''. get_post_image( $post->ID, 'small' ).'\');" >';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this line, you have an echo statement and a semicolon in your statement, remove both and adjust your quotes and you'll be set:

```
echo '<div class="tab_icon tab_'.(empty($post_format) ? 'standard' : $post_format).'" style="background-image: url(' . get_post_image( $post->ID, 'small' ) . ');" >';
```